# set background to gradient color

Tags: android

I want to set the background of my actionbar to a gradient color. For that I have a Colorpicker, in which I can choose the start and the end color. I would like to use these values to set the background.

But I don't know in which format the int values should be to set the gradient drawable to the actionbar. At first I thought the format should something like: `#FFFFFFF` like I use in that case: `actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexFarbe)));` for example.

I tried it with this:

```
 if (x > 10 && x < 138 && y > 316 && y < 356){
            endfarbe_zuletzt_gewählt_global = false;
            startfarbe_zuletzt_gewählt_global = true;
            String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & startFarbe));
            Log.d("startfarbe", "startfarbe " + endFarbe + "|" + hexColor);
            startFarbe_global = hexColor;
            mListener.colorChanged("startFarbe", startFarbe);
        }
```

Here I want to set the actionbar color:

```
if(!(startFarbe.equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&(!(endfarbe.equalsIgnoreCase("")))){
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                    GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                   // new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
                    new int[] {Integer.parseInt(startFarbe), Integer.parseInt(endfarbe)});

            actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
}
```

But then I get the following logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "#0000FF"
```

Comment: Android uses ARGB, you can try create a color like "#AARRGGBB"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` as the `#` within the string you are providing cannot be handled by the `parseInt()` method.

When working with a color string, instead of `Integer.parseInt()` try the `Color` class' method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green',
>   'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray',
>   'darkgray'